# Referring to other variables within a compiler variable definition in install4j

Tags: install4j

Inside an install4j project, is it possible to refer to a compiler variable within the value of another compiler variable? For example, if I've defined the variable "revision" earlier in the list of variables, is it possible to have another variable named "outputDir" with the following value:

```
somedir/${revision}/otherdir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, you just set the value of `outputDir` to

```
somedir/${compiler:revision}/otherdir
```